# AWS Redshift - How to find all tables that count towards the limit on a cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, limit, quota

[Quotas and limits in Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html) defines that the limit for "*Tables for large cluster node type is 9,900*".

That limit has been reached in a cluster.

```
SQL ERROR [500310] [XX000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: 1040
Details:
Maximum tables limit exceeded. The maximum number of tables per cluster is 9900 for this instance type. The limit includes permanent and temporary tables. (pid: xxxxx)
```

In order to know if we are to hit this issue again in a cluster, DevOps wants to setup an alert, but we are failing to find a simple query to identify all tables that count towards that limit.

The closest we've got is with this query to [svv_diskusage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_DISKUSAGE.html):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.tbl) FROM svv_diskusage d;
```

That returned a total of `8,825`. We are `1,075` away.

Temporary tables also count, but we were not even close to be over 1,000 temp tables at the time the exception was thrown.

Any other idea out there that does not include connecting to each database of the cluster to count tables?

Comment: Side-question: Why do you have so many tables? Is each table really unique in terms of schema?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That many tables because of the large volume of data. No, tables are not unique in terms of schema, but splitting the data has resulted in significant benefits, despite going against recommendations.

Comment: That's interesting. Theoretically, good use of `SORTKEY` should make tables very efficient even with billions of rows, as long as the `SORTKEY` is included in the `WHERE` statement. This allows Redshift to 'skip over' disk blocks that don't contain relevant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SVV_DISKUSAGE` view, as documented, only counts permanent tables; it does not count temporary tables that are created within a transaction. [STV_TBL_TRANS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_TBL_TRANS.html) keeps track of the transient tables created during a transaction.

Alternatively, `count(distinct table)` from [STV_BLOCKLIST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_BLOCKLIST.html).

*However,* do you really want to be constantly executing queries to track the number of tables in your cluster? Especially given that transient tables will depend on the number of active transactions, it seems like the wrong approach.

Instead, I'd look at the `TotalTableCount` [CloudWatch metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/metrics-listing.html). It would also be easier to create an alarm on this. With the caveat that you'll probably want to alarm on, say, 95% because the metric probably has low resolution.

Comment: The counts returned from CW Metrics has been the best approach. Not perfect, but very close to our needs. Thanks.